# Seemingly Random 1=1 where clause generated by GORM's where closure

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Sample Program With Problem: https://github.com/HybridProgrammer/GormOneIsOneError

## Problematic GORM Code

```
def query = UserData.where {
        (
                teams { id in me.getAuthorities().id } && status { isOpen == true }
        ) || (
                owner == me && status { isOpen == true }
        )
    }
```

## Summary of the Problem

The generated SQL query occasionally produces a where clause containing 1=1 when I would expect to see teams_alia1_.id in (?)

## Detailed Description of the Problem

I wrote two integration test to illustrate this problem:

### Please see src/intrgration-test/groovy/ExampleITSpec.groovy

#### Integration Test 1

```
void "never fails - direct approach"() {
    given:
    setupData()
    def me = User.first()

    when:
    def query = UserData.where {
        (
                teams { id in me.getAuthorities().id } && status { isOpen == true }
        ) || (
                owner == me && status { isOpen == true }
        )
    }

    then:
    me.getAuthorities().size() == 1
    query.size() == 2
}
```

Always generates SQL

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from user_data this_ inner join status status_ali2_ 
     on this_.status_id=status_ali2_.id 
     inner join workflow_role_teams teams5_ 
     on this_.id=teams5_.user_data_teams_id 
     inner join role teams_alia1_ 
     on teams5_.role_id=teams_alia1_.id 
where 
(((teams_alia1_.id in (?)) and (status_ali2_.is_open=?)) 
or 
(this_.owner_id=? and (status_ali2_.is_open=?))) limit ?
```

#### Integration Test 2

```
void "sometimes fails"() {
    given:
    setupData()
    def me = User.first()

    when:
    def query = exampleService.getMyOrMyTeamsData(me)

    then:
    me.getAuthorities().size() == 1
    query.size() == 2
}
```

Occasionally generates SQL

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from user_data this_ inner join status status_ali2_ 
    on this_.status_id=status_ali2_.id 
    inner join workflow_role_teams teams5_ 
    on this_.id=teams5_.user_data_teams_id 
    inner join role teams_alia1_ 
    on teams5_.role_id=teams_alia1_.id 
where 
((1=1 and (status_ali2_.is_open=?)) 
or 
(this_.owner_id=? and (status_ali2_.is_open=?))) limit ?
```

**Where does the 1=1 come from?**

ExampleService

```
def getMyOrMyTeamsData(User me) {
    // To fix the test Toggle these two lines
    def user = me
//        def user = User.get(me.id)

    def query = UserData.where {
        (
                teams { id in me.getAuthorities().id } && status { isOpen == true }
        ) || (
                owner == user && status { isOpen == true }
        )
    }

    return query

}
```

## Update 1

While debugging the application you can clearly see **authorities** variable is passed along to DetachedCriteria#handleJunction(Closure callable) in the working version but vanishes when called from the service method.

### Integration Test 1 - Has authorities attribute

[image: Integration Test 1 - Has authorities attribute]

### Integration Test 2 - No authorities attribute

[image: Integration Test 2 - No authorities attribute]

## Solution

Please see solution branch
https://github.com/HybridProgrammer/GormOneIsOneError/commit/8c3d77f82081d0367961345b4fc70c789e322318

Comment: What version of grails?

Comment: Grails Version: 3.2.6

Comment: What happens when you use static types instead of `def`?

Comment: Seemed promising. When running in my IDE (IntelliJ) all tests are passing. However running from the command line: grails test-app -integration -Dgrails.env=test test fails every time on line 99 of ExampleITSpec.groovy. I pushed an updated version to static-types branch. My changes: https://github.com/HybridProgrammer/GormOneIsOneError/commit/f24f99fbbc182fa9865c164f8ee82099306c747a

Comment: Ran it again in IntelliJ and the "sometimes fails" test failed again this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the test always fails and I don't know why test 2 and 3 show different behavior, but after I changed `List teams` to `List<Role> teams` in UserData.groovy, test 3 passed.

In the GORM docs the declaration of mapped fields is often omited, which also works in this case.

Hope this also works for you.

Comment: I had to run grails clean once. All tests are passing. Thank you so much!