# GORM's where closure with an "in" Query Drops the where clause in generated SQL

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

**Source Code:** https://github.com/HybridProgrammer/GormIn

**Grails Version:** 3.2.8

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
def query = UserData.where {
    teams { id in teamIds }
}
```

When running the query in Spock test it works correctly. When running it from a Grails service it returns all rows in UserData and does not filter out only those users belonging to the team in teamIds list.

## Spock Tests

### Running Query from Spock Test - Always Passes

```
void "never fails - direct approach"() {
    given:
    setupData()
    def me = User.first()
    def teamIds = me.getAuthorities().id

    when:
    def query = UserData.where {
        teams { id in teamIds }
    }

    then:
    teamIds.size() == 1
    query.size() == 2
}
```

**Generated SQL**

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from user_data this_ inner join workflow_role_teams teams3_ 
    on this_.id=teams3_.user_data_teams_id inner join role teams_alia1_ 
    on teams3_.role_id=teams_alia1_.id 
 where teams_alia1_.id in (?) 
 limit ?
```

### Running Query from Grails Service

#### Occasionally passes in IntelliJ, Never form CLI

```
void "sometimes fails"() {
    given:
    setupData()
    def me = User.first()

    when:
    def query = exampleService.getMyOrMyTeamsData(me)

    then:
    me.getAuthorities().size() == 1
    query.size() == 2
}
```

**exampleService.getMyOrMyTeamsData**

```
def getMyOrMyTeamsData(User me) {
    def teamIds = me.getAuthorities().id

    def query = UserData.where {
        teams { id in teamIds }
    }

    return query
}
```

**Generated SQL**

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from user_data this_ inner join workflow_role_teams teams3_ 
    on this_.id=teams3_.user_data_teams_id inner join role teams_alia1_ 
    on teams3_.role_id=teams_alia1_.id 
limit ?
```

## Solution

Please see solution branch
https://github.com/HybridProgrammer/GormIn/commit/d510e63b3e85b82ce06e24d8a392c10873a8306c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered here:

[Seemingly Random 1=1 where clause generated by GORM's where closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331616/seemingly-random-1-1-where-clause-generated-by-gorms-where-closure)

In grails-app/domain/oneisone/UserData.groovy

```
List teams = new ArrayList()
```

Change to

```
List<Role> teams = new ArrayList()
```

Run grails clean then rerun the tests.